# Programmatically Adding Properties to Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, properties

I am trying to programmatically add properties to an object. This case is a little bit different though, and I am not sure how to approach this issue.

Normally, to apply properties to an object I would apply it in this context:

```
var a = []
var len = result[0].length
for(m=0; m < len; m++){
  a[m] = "b" + m // creates b1-b17 usually, but if the results are shorter it will create them equal to the length of the results
}
const values = {}
for(g=0; g<len; g++){
  values[a[g]] = [];
}
```

This would add an empty array to each property "b1" through "b17" normally, but its dynamic, in case the results are shorter.

Now I would like to do the same thing to this code, but inside the "return" part only. Is there anyway that I can call that and input those variables programmatically like I have done previously?

```
const rowData = tableData.map(result => {
  for(var h in a){
    values[a[h]].push(result[h]);
  }
  return {
    //I want to put properties in here programmatically and dynamically like I did previously
  }
})
```

Thank you guys for your time!

Comment: `creates b1-b17 usually` Really? It *should* create something like `b0-b17`

Comment: I would be much easier to understand what you are asking if you would provide some some input data for `tableData` and show what you want the output to be.

Comment: So you want each member of `tableData` to be turned into an array of `b0`..`b17` type values?  Not at all clear what you're trying tro achieve

Comment: @CertainPerformance it does create b0-b17, my bad. I didnt proof read that part.

Comment: Why isn't your "context" code `const values = {}; for(g = 0; g<len; g++) { values["b"+g] = []; }`?

Comment: @Mark_M tableData input would be something similar to:
   ```[[data1, data2, data3, data4,....], [data11, data22, data33, data44,....],.....]```
my goal would be to have the output be:
  ```[{column1: data1, column2: data2, column3: data3,....}, {column1: data11, column2: data22, column3: data33,....}.......]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn an array like `['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']` into an object with dynamic keys like `column1` using `reduce()`. For example:

```js
let arr = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
let obj = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => (a['column' + (i + 1)] = c, a), {} )

console.log(obj)
```

With that in hand, given an array of such arrays you can combine it with `map()` to get your final result:

```js
let tableData = [['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'], ['data11', 'data22', 'data33', 'data44']]

// for each array in tableData make an object with reduce and  add it to the returned array   
let result = tableData.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, c, i) => (a['column' + (i + 1)] = c, a), {} ))

console.log(result)
```